# How to protect static files with authorization ActionBuilder In Play 2.5 Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have an ActionBuilder I use on most REST endpoints in my Play 2.5 app:

```
  def IfAuthorized(auths: Authorizations*): ActionBuilder[AuthRequestWithAuthorization] = {
    new MyAuthActionBuilder(auths.toList)
  }
```

which I can use as :

```
  def status = IfAuthorized(Editor).async { implicit authReq =>
      //eventually return Result
  }
```

Now I want to wrapp the static files requests in the same `ActionBuilder`. Currently I use this oneliner, which enables me to serve html, js, css etc., all returned/cached without my interference:

```
GET         /ui/*file                  controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

I'm not sure how to shove in the ActionBuilder. A poor attempt to return the initial html page include:

```
  def index()= IfAuthorized(Editor) {  authReq =>
    val contentStream = this.getClass.getResourceAsStream("/public/index.html")
    Ok.chunked(Enumerator.fromStream(contentStream)).as(HTML)
  }
```

This `Action` is only able to return a specific html file, whereas I want all static assets  returned from 1 route, protected by my custom `ActionBuilder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement your own asset controller: The route

```
GET   /auth/*file   controllers.AuthAssets.at(path="/public", file: String)
```

would point to the following endpoint:

```
class AuthAssets extends Controller {
    def at(path: String, file: String) = IfAuthorized(Editor) {  authReq =>
        val contentStream = this.getClass.getResourceAsStream(path + file)
        Ok.chunked(Enumerator.fromStream(contentStream))
    }
}
```